# Log4j.properties does not producing logs with timestamp for LOGGER.info(), LOGGER.error() statements

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have recently added Log4j in my project and all the logs are printing as expected.

Now I have added the timestamp in the log4j.properties file and server-generated logs are printing with the timestamp but which statements I am printing from Logger.info() and Logger.error() it is not printing with the timestamp. This is how my log4j.properties look like:

```
logFileLoc = ${catalina.base}/logs/

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, fileAppender

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}: [%-5p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect Log Messages To A Debug Log File, Support File Rolling !!
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=${logFileLoc}/catalina.out
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}: [%-5p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Whenever I try something like this in my code:

```
LOGGER.debug("creating HomePage");
```

This is what I see in my log file:

```
creating HomePage
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I print the timestamp in LOGGER statements? It will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your configuration with `log4j 1.2.17` and everything works correctly.

I think you have other log4j config file in classpath or you are using system variables(like `log4j.defaultInitOverride` or some others) which have impact on log4j configuration.
I recommend debugging `log4j` initialization in static block of the `LogManager` class and then you will see from which place `log4j` is loading configuration.

if I'm wrong, please provide code for reproducing your issue.

Comment: Hi @saver, thank you for the response.

There is only one log4j.properties configuration file in the project and using dependencies "log4j - 1.2.16", "slf4j-api - 1.7.28" and "slf4j-log4j12 - 1.7.28". In code, I am using these Logger classes "import org.slf4j.Logger; import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;" from slf4j package due to which these logging statements are not printing for log4j. But when I use this "import org.apache.log4j.Logger" class from log4j package its working for me.

Comment: @user3552342 I checked with slfj4 and all works, maybe you can share a sample project to reproduce the problem

Comment: It is resolved for me now. there was a scope defined as test <scope>test</scope> which was making problem to work with slf4j api. After removing this scope it worked for me. Thank you @saver for the help...

Comment: Ou! I glad that you could find issue